# Laravel 5 Socialite how to send rerequest (auth_type=rerequest) to Facebook

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-socialite

I am using Socialite for Facebook registration/authentication and it's working great when user accepts all the permissions on Facebook. 
But I have a problem when user declined one of the permission - especially the e-mail which is necessary in my application to create an account. If the user did it in a mistake and would still like to use Facebook authentication I have to send to Facebook API request with auth_type=rerequest

From Facebook Docs:

> If someone has declined a permission for your app, the login dialog won't let your app re-request the permission unless you pass auth_type=rerequest along with your request.

Is there any way to send that by Socialite?

Comment: Mere coincidence, I'm facing the same problem right now, I could not find any way to send a rerequest yet using Laravel Socialite, for instance I decide create to manually another class to handle this situation when I don't receive the email from the user, another workaround I tried is when the user has declined the email I send another delete call manually to Graph Api to revoke the app from the user settings, this will not login the user in my app and the next time the user clicks to the login button he will be prompt again to share his email address.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I just found the solution:

Add a new `auth_type=rerequest` parameter to the `redirect()`, to do so within your controller create a method where the user can be redirected after decline a permission, then set the method `with()` to append the rerequest parameter to the URL like so:

```php
public function redirect(Socialite $socialite)
{
    return $socialite->driver('facebook')->with(['auth_type' => 'rerequest'])->redirect();
}
```

---

Another workaround as Socialite do not provide a ReRequest out of the box, for a while, so in this case, you de-authorize your app from the user Facebook account after receive the Socialite user response where the user has declined an email permission, then from the login page alerts the user that he must give you the permission to continue and loggin into in your app using Facebook, so the next time the user clicks in the login button he'll see again a Facebook dialog where he can give all permissions.

```php
    /**@var \Laravel\Socialite\Two\User $retrieveUser*/
    $retrieveUser = $social->driver($provider)->user();
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
    $response = $client->delete("https://graph.facebook.com/{$retrieveUser->id}/permissions",
        [
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
            ],
            'form_params' => [
                'access_token' => $retrieveUser->token
            ]
        ]
    );
```

Because this workaround do not follow the Facebook best practices I also suggest you to use another package which has this option out of the box https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk

Comment: It works! you can keep the ['auth_type' => 'rerequest'] param always present in the with() on your redirect method if you want. Even if it is the first time the user logs in, it will work. That parameter is only used by Facebook when the permissions requested differ from the ones previously approved.

Comment: I stuck with similar problem. Maybe some sollutions for Laravel 5.5?

Answer (score 0):

another important aspect when using facebook is not to assume that user will always have email registered with facebook.

Note from facebook:

> Note, even if you request the email permission it is not guaranteed
>   you will get an email address. For example, if someone signed up for
>   Facebook with a phone number instead of an email address, the email
>   field may be empty.

source:[facebook Documentation for Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions)